# xfdesktop --windowlist works only sporadically when called from xbindkeys

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, xfce, xbindkeys

I have `xbindkeys` setup to show the XFCE window list when I press the thumb button on my mouse.
Here's my `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
# Thumb button on mouse brings up the window list
"xfdesktop --windowlist"
    b:10
```

It works about once every twenty button presses, regardless of which monitor or window I click on. I already edited the command to write the return code of xfdesktop to a file, but it always returned 0, also there never was any output (like errors) from the `xfdesktop` command, even when it didn't actually bring up the window list.

When called via leopard shortcut or Terminal, it works fine every time. So the problem seems to be something about the combination of `xbindkeys` and `xfdesktop`.

EDIT: When run in `gdb`, it works every time. It also works when I change the command to `sleep 0.1; xfdesktop --windowlist`, for whatever reason. So I've got it working now, though I still haven't got a clue *why* it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because using `b:10` the command is called on the button down event, and the subsequent button up removes the popup.

I solved lunching the command only when button is released using:

```
"xfdesktop --windowlist"
    b:10 + Release
```